# Spark encode character in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Persian text/file and I'm trying to count words in it.
It works with English and `ASCII`. But does not work with Persian characters.

Here's my code:

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("TestSpark")
sc = SparkContext(conf= conf)


input = sc.textFile("c:\spark\\test_text.txt")
words = input.flatMap(lambda x : x.split())
words = words.flatMap(lambda x : x[0])
wordsCount = words.countByValue()


for word, count in wordsCount.items():
    cleanWord = word.encode("ascii","ignore") # I tried UTF-8 but exception happened
    if(cleanWord):
       print(cleanWord.decode()+" "+ str(count))
```

My text file:

[image]

Comment: what is your file encoding ? you should work with UTF8 files.

Comment: This is not the most optimized way to do it. apply function on your dataframe rather than iterating it and cleaning words.

Comment: @Steven Yes it is UTF-8

Comment: what do you mean it does not work ? what is happening ? any error ? please provide debugging details

Answer (score 0):

what if you just print the word :

```py
for word, count in wordsCount.items():
   print(word+" "+ str(count))
```

When your doing that, you have a string in word variable. you can see it's type, is it a byte or a string ? can you print it ? start from that.